# Application using a DLL, but Visual Studio 2010 not showing it in Modules window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to figure out the answer. I've currently got a C++ application that's loading & utilizing a DLL (I compiled both the application & the DLL with VS 2010). I'm positive it's using the DLL, because a) if I rename the DLL, I get a not found exception, and b) it's displaying output that only comes from (and I can change it to see the output change) inside the DLL.

My problem is that in Visual Studio's Modules window while debugging, the DLL does not appear to be loaded. Because of this, obviously its got no symbols and I can't set breakpoints... But this doesn't make any sense to me as it's clearly using the DLL.

I've seen several other similar questions, and the answer has generally been too look at whether the code is native, managed, or mixed, and set the "Attach to Process" field accordingly. I've tried all the options there, and made sure my Debugger Type is set to "Mixed" (though I've tried it with Native & Managed as well, just to verify none of these solve the issue).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried `::LoadLibrary` on your DLL?  You don't have any managed code in your DLL?  Also, can you add code to issue a debug break from your DLL method:  `_asm { int 3 }` to see what happens?

Comment: What happens when you try to set a breakpoint?  If something's wrong, you should get the empty circle, if you mouse over that, a tooltip might give some extra info.

Comment: I have not tried `::LoadLibrary`, though the way it's set up I'm not actually attempting to modify the main program, just the DLL, but I'll try giving it a shot just for debugging purposes. Thanks for the tip on the `_asm{ int 3 }`, I'll give that a shot too. And no, no managed code in the DLL, all native.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me and I found the project->properties->Debug page and clicked the box to Enable native code debugging. I was doing a C# project accessing a C++ / native dll

budward

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas:

1. check output windows it the DLL symbols are missing.
2. Make sure dllname.pdb file exist beside the DLL
3. make sure visual studio solution has two projects (EXE,DLL) projects
4. switch to DEBUG mode instead of RELEASE mode.
5. run process explorer (download it from MS) and check the path of the DLL that is bonded to the EXE in runtime.

Finally the ultimate solution:

1. Open Process Explorer and search for your DLL name.
2. Find which EXE is using it.
3. Goto VS and attach your debugger to that EXE.

I hope any of those fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately I verified that all 4 of those are in the states they should be in. The .pdb/.dll files are there (and recently regenerated), there are two projects, one for each, and I'm running in debug.

Comment: when you press F5 to start debugging check the output window to make sure the symbols for the DLLs is loaded and the DLL itself is loaded.

Comment: I have added 5th idea and you did not check idea #1

Comment: Sorry, I did do step one... there's just no output. And I've tried process explorer; it shows the same as modules, so for some reason it doesn't count as "loaded" even though I know it's getting executed, because of the print statements.